# Виды существительных

Tags: морфология

Я не понимаю вещественные, конкретные, отвлеченные и собирательные существительные.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: А еще Вы не понимаете, что перед "пожалуйста" ставится запятая, а предложения начинаются с большой буквы. Пишите вопрос, так потрудитесь хотя бы писать его без ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

**Конкретные** существительные называют определенные предметы и явления действительности, воспринимаемые органами чувств. Они легко подвергаются счету и сочетаются с количественными числительными (*восемь студенток, один карандаш, три сестры* и т.д.). Употребляются в единственном и множественном числе (двор - дворы, книга - книги и т.д.). Не изменяются по числам лишь некоторые из них: несклоняемые существительные (кофе, пальто, радио и под.) и слова, употребляющиеся только в форме множественного числа (норжницы, брюки, шахматы, Альпы...). Конкретные существительные могут быть одушевленными и неодушевленными, в то время как абстрактные существительные - только неодушевленными.

---

**Абстрактные** (отвлеченные) существительные обозначают отвлеченные понятия, свойтсва, качества, действия, состояния (доброта, счастье, боль, грусть, слава, движение, терпение, тишь...). В большинстве своем они образуются от прилагательных и глаголов при помощи суффиксов -ость (храбрость, трусость), -от- (глухота, доброта), -изн- (крутизна, дороговизна), -изм (гуманизм, сююреализм), -ин- (величина, ширина), -ств-о (коварство, пространство), - аций-а (стилизация, эвакуация), -ений-е (терпение, уважение), -к-а (бомбежка, подготовка) и др. В отличие от конкретных сущ.абстрактные употребляются только в форме единственного числа (реже - только во множественном) и не сочетаются с количественными числительными. Нечасто наблюдаемое изменение по числам у абстрактных существительных сопровождается, как правило, изменением лексического значения формы множественного числа (ее конкретизацией): радость - семейные радости, холод - зимние холода, талант - молодые таланты и т.д.

---

**Вещественные** существительные обозначают однородные по составу вещества: полезные ископаемые, хим. элементы и их соединения (нефть, латунь, руда, соль...), пищевые продукты (винегрет, кисель, чай, молоко, масло...), растения, схоз.культуры (ячмень, овес, картофель...), виды тканей (шелк, крепдешин, хлопок), лекарства, различные материалы, прочвы, отходы производства (асфальт, глина, опилки...), атмосферные осадка и др. Вещество, обозначенное таким существительным, может быть измерено (при помощи веса, объема и пр.). Поэтому большинство вещественных сущ. не сочетается с количественными числительными, не изменяется по числам. Обычно они употребляются в форме какого-нибудь одного числа: только единственного (известь, сахар) или только множественного (макароны, дрожжи, чернила...). Изменение вещественных сущ. по числам наблюдается, когда формы ед. и мн. числа различаются лексическим значением. Формы множ.числа обозначают не множество предметов, а различные их виды, сорта, типы (грязь - лечебные грязи, масло - растительные масла) или сплошную массу вещества (жиры, пески, снега).

---

**Собирательные** существительные обозначают совокупность однородных единиц: множество предметов, растений или животных как одно неделимое целое. Одним из важнейших признаков собирательных существительных является то, что они не образуют форм множественного числа и не сочетаются с количественными числительными. Исходная форма таких сущ. - форма ед. числа - выражает множественность (березняк, вороньё, листва), что сближает их с формами множ.числа конкретных сущ., сравн.: *студенчество - студенты, литва - листья*. Различаются эти слова семантикой: ед.число собирательных сущ. обозначает неделимое множество как целое (оно не подвергается счету), множественное число конкретных сущ. называет множество, легко разложимое на отдельные составляющие и поддающееся счету.
!!! От собирательных сущ. необходимо отличать слова *народ, группа, коллектив, толпа, куча, полк, стадо, стая, табун* и т.п. Если нужно пояснить, спрашивайте. И так ответ на ваш вопрос занял слишком много места.

Отвечаю на второй вопрос (**от Элен**). В смысловом плане существительные *народ, группа, коллектив, толпа, куча, полк, стадо, стая, табун* и т.п. обозначают совокупность и на этом основании часто ошибочно включаются в разряд собирательных существительных. Но грамматически эти слова образуют формы множественного числа, сочетаются с количественными числительными и, таким образом, представляют собой обычные нарицательные конкретные существительные.

Answer (score 1):

А *народ, группа, коллектив, толпа, куча, полк, стадо, стая, табун* к какой группе существительных относятся?